# How to multiply the different columns in different tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do multiplication the data in table column.

EXAMPLE:

the **reproduced_count(1)** in **bug_table**,

the **bug_priority_id(2)** in  **bug_detalis_table**,

the **bug_type_id(5)** in  **bug_detalis_table**

the multiplication of this three columns the output is 1*2*5 = 10
how can I get this output in postgresql

```
(select reproduced_count 
 from project.pm_task_run_bug_details 
 where pm_task_run_bug_detail_id = 260) 
 *
 (select bug_priority_id*bug_type_id 
  from project.pm_task_run_bugs 
  where pm_task_run_bug_id = 261)
```

Comment: The most naive approach could be select (select reproduced_count from bug_table) * (select bug_priority_id*bug_type_id from bug_detalis_table);

Comment: its showing the syntax error near the * of two tables

Comment: you want to multiple the total values in all the rows of each column or multiple values in each row separately? It's not clear, because there's no proper sample data, or any way for us to understand the foreign key relationship between the tables. Give a clearer description of the scenario by including schema information, proper sample data and proper expected result. It's unclear now whether your example is a sum of all rows, or just a sample of one specific row, or something else entirely.

Comment: each row separately and i am using where condition because of the particular id have to multiple

Comment: Multiplying by `bug_type_id` seems highly suspicious.  Your question needs sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.